# Is it OK to mention Google's name for easy to answer questions?

Tags: discussion

I have seen many comments, on some low-quality questions, lacking research effort, saying things like:

- > Google is your friend!
- > A Google search would have given you the answer!
- > Google!!!!!

And things like that. Aren't these *promoting* Google?

Should such comments be flagged? If yes, then with what reason? If no, then why not?

Comment: The problem with these are not that they "promote" Google. It is that they are derogatory and unhelpful in the least. The are not welcoming to new users and don't explain the problem with the question.

Comment: @Oded The latter is included. My question is: How should I flag them?

Comment: I'd say - not constructive.

Comment: ..which is why I usually copy/paste their exact title into the Google search box and, if ther eare more than 'About 50,000 results', and the first page explains multiple times what the OP's problem is, I have no issue whatsoever with commenting.

Comment: It is just another way to say "this question lacks research effort".  But more helpful, indicating that Google is very likely to spit out the answer.  And not Bing or DuckDuckGo or whatever.  Sure, questioners and SE employees are rarely happy about it, they expect you to answer the question or search for a duplicate instead.  Which is certainly a lot more constructive than flagging the comment, that just pushes the problem to somebody else.  Flagging is the *least* constructive thing you could do by a long margin.

Comment: I suspect that many such posters already know the answer, as do the friends/colleagues in their voting rings.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36291605/c-strcmp-not-working

Comment: @MartinJames Are you hinting at cheating the reputation system? But won't such questions be downvoted much much more than they are upvoted?

Comment: @Hackerdarshi I don't know for sure.  I can say that I am at a loss to otherwise explain 5 upvotes on an answer to a 'newline left in stdin' question - something that has nearly as many dups as 'i++ + ++i'.

Comment: @Hackerdarshi the other snag is that downvoting answers that are obviusly multi-duplicates, but are inherently correct, seems like a waste of rep.  Sometimes, if I've earned some reasonable rep over a day, I'll blow 5 on downvoting all the answers to such questions.

Comment: @MartinJames Oh yes. When you have some good answers in the day, that are sure to upvoted, and you are near the 200 cap! Nice idea!

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8724/how-should-we-deal-with-google-questions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While Google is indeed our friend, we can rephrase the comment and make it more constructive. Simply commenting "Google!!" is not really welcoming and polite.

If you insist to redirect someone to Google (which most probably will link you to Stack Overflow again), you can post a better comment, for example:

> [Simple Google search](https://www.google.co.il/search?q=google&oq=google&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l4j0.910j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) should answer your question, please try to do a minimal research in your future posts.

It might be a good idea to redirect users to the [help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help) so they better understand how Stack Overflow works and what do we expect on every post.

> Should such comments be flagged? If yes, then with what reason? If no, then why not?

I think it's better if you try to find a duplicate and vote to close in that case, or you can redirect to a *specific* reference that might help OP better than just saying "Google!". Flagging should be your last decision.

Comment: I agree.  Flagging in this situation where you can actually fix the problem to some extent is just passing the buck.